# Binding of Label Text from mongodb retrieved value

Tags: mongodb, variables, text, binding, label

I'm having issues binding my label text to the userValue calculated from my mongoDB collection.
I've tried this multiple ways now and would like to simply have this work in the Xamarin's code behind. Please would you provide better guidance than is already out there as current posts on this have not worked...

My XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="YourLableName"
      Text="{Binding UserValue, StringFormat='{0:0}'}" 
/>
```

My CS:

```
 public HomePage() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
            UserData();
        }

public async void UserData()
        {
            var userId = HomePage.userIdentity;
            var usersValues = await MongoService.GetUserModel(userId);

            foreach (var test in usersValues)
            {
                userValue = test.usersValueX.ToString();
            }

            UserValue = userValue;
        }

        private string _UserValue; 
        public string UserValue
        {
            get { return _UserValue; }
            set
            {                
                _UserValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserValue");
            }
        }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
```

Thank you :)

P.s. I have breakstopped this at UserValue and the value is retrieved in the UserData method however it still does not bind to my label text...

Comment: Can somebody help me? I've followed these instructions but my binding still isnt working... https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-binding/

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because my content page was wrapped in a control template :/ .